# I can't get autotest working with Rails 3.0.4 and MongoID 2.0.0.rc.7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec2, autotest

I'm not able to get autotest started. It just hangs after it clears the console screen:

```
$ autotest
loading autotest/rails_rspec2


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

there is nothing in test.log. Other searches for this problem on S.O. don't provide an answer.

- autotest 4.4.6
- ZenTest 4.4.2
- Rails 3.0.4
- MongoID 2.0.0.rc.7

Maybe there is another place I could be looking for autotest errors?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that an update to autotest (or rspec?) something somewhere made the config info in my `~/.autotest` file obsolete. So i commented everything out except for:

```
require 'autotest/fsevent'
require 'autotest/growl'
```

and now it appears to be working!

no more: `Autotest.add_hook(:initialize) {|autotest| ...`